# how to represent out of range number in binary?

Tags: binary

In 2 complements I read from wikipedia, the range is from -128 to 127. So I wonder how do we represent 128 in 2 complement as it is out of range above?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement
(Use 8 bytes to represent)

Comment: @tsubasa - you seem to be stuck on the idea that "2s complement" == "8 bits", but it's not. Are you stuck with using 8 bits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use more bits.

The range -128 to +127 is 256 unique values, which is 8 bits.  If you need a larger range, you need more bits.

There is nothing restricting 2s-complement numbers to 8-bit values.  For instance, a 16-bit 2s-complement number ranges from -32768 to +32767.

Comment: But I heard about the wrap-around terminology? Does it use more bits in wrap-around?

Comment: Isn't it still allowed in 2-complement: 1+127 = 128?

Comment: When the leftmost bit of a 2s-complement number is set, then it's a negative number.  Essentially, half of the numbers you can represent with a certain number of bits are negative, and the other half are non-negative.  "Wrapping around" is symmetric for any size 2s-complement binary number.

Comment: Actually, all bits on mean -1 in 2s complement.  -127 is 10000000

Comment: Yes, you're right. Haven't thought about 2s complement for a long time, but a quick trip to the Wikipedia page reveals that you're correct.

Answer (score 1):

8-bit gives you the range: `[-2^7 , 2^7-1] = [-128,127]`

In general, 2's complement using **n-bit** can represent numbers in the range:

```
-2^(n-1) to +2^(n-1)-1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't, if you've only got 8 bits to work with. Unless you're willing to treat treat`1000 0000`as *both* −128 and +128.

Comment: "treat 1000 0000 as both −128 and +128": how would you then differentiate between the two??

Comment: Depends on the context. If you're adding you might want to allow +128 as the max result, and conversely if you're subtracting/decrementing, you might want to allow -128 as the min. I didn't say it was necessarily a good idea, just a possibility.